# why a modules is loaded into kernel even if the config option is m

Tags: kernel

the config option which determines whether the udp_tunnel module is compiled into the kernel is CONFIG_NET_UDP_TUNNEL. And the CONFIG_NET_UDP_TUNNEL in .config of Ubuntu is M, which should not be loaded into kernel automatically. But the result below shows that the udp_tunnel is loaded into kernel, which is confused to me.

```
$ modinfo udp_tunnel
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-51-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/udp_tunnel.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     0A315BA6124B0664F4D23FB
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           udp_tunnel
vermagic:       5.3.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

$ echo $?
0
```

shows the modules udp_tunnel is loaded into the kernel and

Answer (score 1):

Looking up the information about a module does not mean it is loaded. modinfo will look in `/lib/modules/version` for it also.

If you want to know if it is loaded then use lsmod. Example:

```
doug@s18:/boot$ lsmod | grep udp
xt_tcpudp              20480  9
x_tables               45056  9 xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,xt_CHECKSUM,ip6_tables,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE,iptable_mangle
```

Now if the module is force loaded:

```
doug@s18:/boot$ sudo modprobe udp_tunnel
[sudo] password for doug:
doug@s18:/boot$ lsmod | grep udp
udp_tunnel             16384  0
xt_tcpudp              20480  9
x_tables               45056  9 xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,xt_CHECKSUM,ip6_tables,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE,iptable_mangle
```

Comment: Is lsmod accurate? Because one of my user space program depends on module udp_tunnel. The CONFIG_NET_UDP_TUNNEL is M. And the result of lsmod does not list modules udp_tunnel. But the program still works. I have two guesses: 1)I directly download Ubuntu binary from official site and do not compile  from scratch. Is there something special when ubuntu community create Ubuntu image? 2) before running the program modify one config in .config, but the config is not CONFIG_NET_UDP_TUNNEL. It's to show if my program can work. Then I "make modules" "make modules install".

Comment: does "make modules install" command install all modules which equals "M" ?

Comment: As far as I know lsmod is accurate. I don't know about the rest.